# Employee Leave Balances

Tags: wss-3.0, site-template, workflow

How can I use the Absence Request and Vacation Schedule Management template to keep track of everyone's balances.
Say an employee had 15 days of leave available on May 1.  For each day of vacation they take from that date their balance decreases.
Can this be done?
I've been all over the web looking for an answer and am about ready to give up :(

Comment: @Nav could you please explain this a little more ?

Answer (score 2):

You could always apply a workflow to the list so that whenever time taken off it updates a secondary list containing available vacation hours for your users.  You could then kick off a second workflow to notify you when that column value drops to zero

Comment: I was thinking the exact same thing but I don't know how to do the math.
To enter a request for one day off, a user would likely select the day they want and check the "All Day Event" check-box.  How do I take that all day event and give it a value of "1" to subtract from my balances?

Comment: The all day event is a boolean type so you could do a logic check on whether that field equals yes. If so, update the appropriate timeoff value for a full day's time.  If it says no, subtract the alternate selected amount.

Answer (score 1):

I did this by having an employee leave list which has the employees name, allowance and balance. When an employee makes a request they enter the days taken (which gets approved by their manager).

Then minus the days requested from their holiday balance in the employee leave list. Matching the employee name and the to the name of the employee who created the holiday request.